# Xubuntu - can't send epub and mobi file to my phone via bluetooth?

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, epub, mobi

I can send pdf and jpg files to my phone on bluetooth but why can I send epub or mobi files?

Is it something to do with my phone setting (Xiaomi Redmi Note 3) or my Xubuntu's?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today. There seems to be a whitelist of allowed file types that doesn't include epub. The simplest workaround seems to be using another file sharing method. Another (not tested) is packing your chosen files into a zip archive and sending that. You could also try temporarily changing file extensions to *.jpg, sending them and changing the extensions back.

A Google search showed some relevant info, so I'll just link it here in case someone finds it useful. This question is for app developers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2942454 . And this article is about allowing more file types on a rooted phone: https://htc-one.gadgethacks.com/how-to/bypass-androids-file-type-restrictions-bluetooth-file-sharing-0157237/ .